# Pass argument from makefile to cocotb testbench

Tags: makefile, cocotb

Given the D-FF example from [cocotb/examples/dff/](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/tree/master/examples/dff). What is the proper way to pass an argument from the `Makefile` to the cocotb testbench `dff_cocotb.py` without modifying the native cocotb makefiles?

I tried to modify line 30 of [cocotb/examples/dff/tests/Makefile](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/master/examples/dff/tests/Makefile):

```
sim:
    $(MODULE).py testarg
```

respectively

```
sim: $(MODULE).py
$(MODULE).py:
    $(MODULE).py testarg
```

which doesn't work and shows the error message:

```
usage: cocotb [-h] test
cocotb: error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm. It looks like the Makefile launches the simulator, which in turn invokes cocotb via VPI hooks into the simulator.  If I understand correctly, it specifies the target testbench to the cocotb framework through environment variables.

This implies you may be able to pass your arguments to your $(MODULE).py using the environment as well.  I.e., launch make as:

```
MY_TB_ARGS=<whatver> make
```

and in $(MODULE).py, access them via

```
import os
myTbArgs = os.environ['MY_TB_ARGS']
```

Comment: I'm using ghdl as simulator, but I don't want to pass an argument to the simulator directly. I just want to pass the argument from the `Makefile` to the file `dff_cocotb.py` and parse it there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
make PLUSARGS="+my_arg1=123 +my_arg2=456"
```

and access it through `cocotb.plusargs`

```
>>>print(cocotb.plusargs)
{'my_arg1': '123', 'my_arg2': '456'}
```